# Errors when trying to update using apt-get

Tags: apt

I get errors when I try to install any software. The errors are

```
Reading package lists... Error!
E: Could not open file /var/cache/apt/pkgcache.bin - open (22: Invalid argument)
E: Failed to truncate file - ftruncate (9: Bad file descriptor)
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

When I try to update a system with `sudo apt-get update`, I encounter other errors like

```
W: Failed to fetch http://tz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91. 189. 92. 192 80]
```

and many others.

I am new to Ubuntu.

Comment: @jokerdino The 404 error here is not from a PPA. So are you sure [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa) is really the best question to dupe this to?

Comment: @EliahKagan I always understood that question as "fix the problem _using_ a PPA". Probably that is the source of this problem. I still think this we have covered this issue somewhere..

Comment: @jokerdino Well, both that question's error messages and its answers are PPA-specific. And why would you *use* a PPA to fix a 404 message about a package available in an official repository? I agree that this is almost certainly a duplicate, of something. Maybe ask in chat?

Comment: @EliahKagan My mistake, really.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Run `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`
2. Add these  lines to it

   ```
   deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main universe restricted multiverse
   deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main universe restricted multiverse

   deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main universe restricted multiverse
   deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main universe restricted multiverse

   deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main universe restricted multiverse
   deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main universe restricted multiverse
   ```
3. Save the file and quit the text editor.
4. Run `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help, i still get the same errors..

Comment: Why specifically the Italian mirror? Also, **why *add* these lines, rather than changing the current ones to the Italian mirror?** With multiple mirrors enabled providing the same software, there is no guarantee that the working mirror will be used.